# C++ Windows Forms Application - XML edit existing xml child node

Tags: c++, .net, xml, c++-cli

I have some problems with editing existing child node, I don't know if its possible but I hope it is. I tried almost everything.
This is part of code that I use to retrieve first childnode text

```
int x;

void ReadX()
{
String ^ strFilename = L"test.xml";
XmlDocument ^ testxml = gcnew XmlDocument;

if (File::Exists(strFilename))
{
testxml->Load(strFilename);
XmlElement ^ elm = testxml->DocumentElement;
XmlNodeList ^ lstVideos = elm->ChildNodes;
//MessageBox::Show(elm->Name);
//MessageBox::Show(elm->InnerText);
x = Convert::ToInt32(lstVideos[0]->InnerText);
}
```

and on button click

```
textBox1->Text=System::Convert::ToString(x);
```

What i would like to do is on button2 click to input value from textBox1 to lstVideos[0]->InnerText
Please don't link me msdn because I already worked with their examples, and I didn't manage to solve it.
I still have to learn a lot about xml, what it would to is edit text of X1, my code above reads X1's text. Would probably be easier to read childnode by name, but I don't yet know how to do that.

This is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Coords>
 <X1>10010</X1>
 <X2>200</X2>
 <X3>300</X3>
 <X4>400</X4>
 <X5>500</X5>
</Coords>
```

Comment: I added .net and c++-cli tags, as this is more of a .net question than a C++ question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since InnerText is a String^ and textBox1->Text is a String^, why not:

```
lstVideos[0]->InnerText = textBox1->Text
```

Also, since both are strings, there is really no reason to convert the InnerText to an int, then back in the first place.

Comment: I tried that and for some reason it doesn't work, probably because I'm converting it to int and back to string. Only reason I'm using it as an int because its not in the main project file, its in include header :(

Comment: Never mind. I had issue somewhere else, that part worked correctly. Ty very much.